# Run a job 10 minutes after another job with quartz cron

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

Basically I want to run a monitoring job after 10 minutes. For that I need to add 10 minutes to the actual cron I have from original job. This 10 minutes is like buffer and expecting that it will be enough for original job to complete. In other cases my monitoring job will alert me. Assuming I use quartz cron.

I tried parsing the cron but it leads to too many cases and quickly becoming complex to understand.

but cron expressions have *,?, ranges, increments , comma-separated numbers etc
Is it even advisable to do so?

sample code:

```
static String addMinutes(String period) throws ParseException {
    CronExpression cron = new CronExpression(period);
    String[] arr = period.split(" ");
    String minutes = arr[1];
    String hours = arr[2];
    if(minutes.contains(",")){
        
    } else if (minutes.contains("-")) {
        
    } else if (minutes.contains("/")) {
        
    } else if (isInteger(minutes)) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(minutes);
        i = (i+9) % 59;
        arr[1] = Integer.toString(i);
        //change hour
        if(i > 49 && isInteger(hours)){
            int h = Integer.parseInt(hours);
            h = (h+1) % 24;
            arr[2] = Integer.toString(h);
        }
    }
    return period;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Would you be able to share some code to see what you are working with so we can answer as precisely as possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I cant share in full but updated above with some code on how I was thinking to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you need to run these task at a specific time of day:

```
00 16 * * * /home/theUser/alca/test1.sh
10 16 * * * /home/theUser/alca/test2.sh
```

These are two jobs and the second job should be in second line.  You see that the first job will run daily at 4 PM and the second job will run at 4:10 PM.

Comment: the question is different sir